# css selector and @media rule in a single declaration

Tags: css, css-selectors, darkmode

I have a css file that has dark mode theme. My css file is something like this:

```css
html.dark {
    /* Dark mode properties */
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    /* Dark mode properties */
}
```

Since they have the same dark mode properties; it's better to use a single dark mode properties for both of them to decrease the css file size and increase page load.

Is there a way to do a selector and a @media rule in a single declaration something like this?:

```css
html.dark, @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    /* Dark mode properties */
}
```

Comment: This might be helpful: https://web.dev/prefers-color-scheme/#dark-mode-in-practice

Comment: Those properties would need to appear in a style rule with a selector - they can't appear in a top-level @media rule. Unless you're using "properties" to mean collectively both declaration blocks (just the property: value; statements themselves) and style rules (selectors and declarations). If the purpose of html.dark is for GD, I recommend sticking with it and discarding the at-rule - if your goal is to reduce duplication and overhead there's no reason why you should maintain two disparate dark mode implementations.